# static marker from a mysql array

Tags: php, mysql, loops, static

I have a little problem I can't figure out how to solve.

I have an SQL result with 3 rows and I want to put the id from each row into a static marker ie.

```
MARKER_1 = 4
MARKER_2 = 5
MARKER_3 = 6
```

How can I do that so I get my static markers but with dynamic values?

I can't do it with a normal

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "marker"? Can you post a usage example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($i == 1) {
        $marker_1 = $row;
    } elseif($i == 2) {
        $marker_2 = $row;
    } elseif($i == 3) {
        $marker_3 = $row;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

i would recommend using an array like this

```
$results = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $results[] = $row;
}
```

and then access it via:

```
$results[0] // or $results[1] and so on. you can even loop that :)
```

hope that helps

Comment: may i ask why this is voted down? what's wrong? did i misunderstand a question?

Comment: The array solution works perfectly :) Thank you! I run the results array through a foreach loop and sets the markers as I want them.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "MARKER_".$row['id'];
echo"=". $row['value'];
}
```